# MVC 3 Load/Unload Partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I am new to MVC. I am using MVC3. I have created three partial views which are being shared in multiple other views. 
So i am loading each partial view in separate div controls

```
<div data-role="content" id="div_parent" style="background-color: #454545"
        <div id="div1" style="display:none">
            @Html.Partial("_View1")
        </div>
        <div id="div2" style="display:none;">
            @Html.Partial("_View2")
        </div>
        <div id="div3" style="display:none">
            @Html.Partial("_View3")
        </div>
</div>
```

I am hiding all views on

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#div1").hide();
            $("#div2").hide();
            $("#div3").hide();

        }); // end of change 

    });
```

And on Select options i am showing respective views

```
<select id="views" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false">
                 <option value="view1" data-mini="true">view1</option>
                 <option value="view2" data-mini="true">view2</option>
                 <option value="view3" data-mini="true">view3</option>
 </select>





function ShowView(viewType) 
{
      $("#div1").show();
      $("#div2").hide();
      $("#div3").hide();
}
```

But problem here is in all 3 views i have same name javascript functions so when i click on button on view1 it is calling javascript function of view2 or view3. So eventhough divs are hidden javascripts functions are still loaded on the html page.
This is one scenario. there are other problems also. So my question is how to avoid this situation. 
How to load/unload views so that it will not render whole html in the view and just hide it.

Comment: so, are you wanting to only render the div that's visible, or fix your javascript so it'll show/hide the correct div when the select changes value?

Comment: There seems to be javascript code missing. You're stating it calling javascript code from view2 or view3 (I think you mean partial) but you haven't shown the code.

Comment: i want to load javascript functions of only visible div

Comment: As @Zruty replied below, you do not provide enough info to help you with script function.
But in general, the proper solution would be to namespace or rename those functions. As partial view is really inserted as a piece of html onto the page and then rendered along with a page. You can not unload it on hide.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this situation make sure that you have single javascript function which will will accept the value as parameters and basis on that you can hide or show respective divs

for eg: This is just a prototype

```
function ShowView(id) 
{
  switch(id){
  case "div1" :
     $("#div1").show();
     $("#div2").hide();
     $("#div3").hide();  
     break;  
  .... // Add other cases
  }
}
```

Comment: Jatin, Yes i have only one Javascript function to hide/show the div

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you have JavaScript functions in each of your partial views, and when you load them all simultaneously, there's a naming conflict, because the functions are named the same.

You cannot easily 'unload' or 'hide' or 'un-execute' the JavaScript you have loaded.

I would suggest renaming the functions (for example, putting them into 'namespaces') to avoid the conflict.

Also, the code snippets you provide give little to no information about the actual problem you have.